# What is a startup code in C for Microcontrollers ? When / Why / How it should be modified?

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, startup

This is a general question about startup code. I know it's like the bootloader or the first thing that run after reset or power up and it call the main function.

But i want to know it main / core functionnalities.

For example (Searching in google),

Startup code is executed immediately upon reset of the target system. The Keil startup
code performs (optionally) the following operations in order:

```
 Clears internal data memory
 Clears external data memory
 Clears paged external data memory
 Initializes the small model reentrant stack and pointer
 Initializes the large model reentrant stack and pointer
 Initializes the compact model reentrant stack and pointer
 Initializes the 8051 hardware stack pointer
 Transfers control to code that initializes global variables or to the main C function if
there are no initialized global variables
```

Nb: The startup code is always written in assembly since it depend on the CPU target.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Start up code is just that. It's the code that's run at start up. It does whatever it needs to do to prepare for the rest of the code to execute.

Comment: @RossRidge Thanks but i really need to know what it actually do to prepare the code in details. In order to be able to change it / customize it. Any details / ressources are welcome ;)

Comment: There's no better answer than that. You'd might as well be asking what exactly do computer programs do in general.

Comment: @RossRidge I don't understund what you meant. The startup code is very specific and i don't think this is a general question. As i said you can talk about any type of MCUs. Regards

Comment: Startup code is also responsible for initializing the hardware to a defined state - That's obviously entirely different for a vehicle on-board computer than it is for a nuclear power plant.

Comment: it doesnt have to be assembly, but you have a chicken and egg problem if it isnt, the C code that does the bootstrapping for C (if C is used) cannot make the same assumptions as normal C programs (that there is an initialized .data, that .bss is zeroed, cant use any other C code (memset, memcpy) that has these assumptions).  So generally asm is used to avoid that problem.  But is not strictly required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned that the startup code calls main so I'll assume that you are talking about startup code for a C/C++ application.  The startup code is responsible for setting up the C run-time environment for the application.  That includes:

- copying the initial values of initialized variables from ROM to RAM
- zeroing out the RAM for uninitialized variables
- setting up the stack pointer
- for C++ applications, it calls the constructors for any global or static object instances
- finally, call main

The startup code may also do some hardware initialization but this is hardware specific and not necessarily a requirement.  For example, If the hardware uses a PLL to raise the clock frequency then the startup code might setup the PLL first thing so that the remaining startup code executes at full speed.  If the board has external devices on the address/data bus then the processor's external memory controller is typically configured in the startup code.  Or if the hardware has a watchdog then the startup code might disable it so that it doesn't reset before the application has an opportunity to configure it.

I don't typically do application specific hardware initialization in the startup code.  Rather, I will initialize GPIO, timers, and serial ports within my application, after main is called.

The compiler tool chain typically provides startup code for the hardware environments that it supports.  This example startup code is probably fine for most applications and you may never have to modify it.  But if there is something specialized about your hardware or run-time environment then you may need to customize the startup code.  When I have had to customize the startup code I have always just taken the example startup code and modified it to suit my needs.  I don't remember ever writing startup code from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

All computer programs work under the assumption that the world in which they execute, is set up to match their expectations.

Assume you have a program, P, that assumes the value of a variable X is zero when P starts.

If you place that program P into your microprocessor as the code startup point, it won't work.... because the value of X is not guaranteed to be zero. (RAM memory locations tend to power up containing garbage.)

You solve that problem by inserting startup code that makes the assumptions true, e.g., you place code at the startup to zero the variable X, and then pass control to your program.   Whatever assumptions are required by your program, you need to implement in the startup code.

Now I wrote a pretty general description.  When we talk about real microprocessors, there are usually low-level assumptions that must be satisfied:

- If the machine has a stack pointer, it points to some real memory as opposed to holding garbage
- Any I/O ports or special hardware needed are "ready to use" (they often require configuration; consider a memory bank select register or a priority interrupt controller)
- The location of your program is known

If these three assumptions are needed, the startup code will address them by:

- Loading the SP register with a constant that is known be a RAM address
- Executing special instructions or writing various magic constants to the necessary I/O ports to configure them for use
- Set the PC to the known location of your program (usually a JMP xxxx instruction)

Every MCU controller program has different assumptions about the world.  You custom code your startup code to satisfy these assumptions.

Generally, there aren't a lot of these assumptions, and many MCU programs can get by with a small, carefully chosen set.   Consequently the startup instructions tend to be treated separately from the program (otherwise, you could simply prepend them to your program, and sometimes people do).